# What does "non-conformant" harmonization mean?

Tags: harmony, chord-voicings

In context with this question:

[Take 6: What chords are making this style so jazzy?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/106799/take-6-what-chords-are-making-this-style-so-jazzy)

I came across the term  **non-conformant harmonization**:

*Non-Conformant Harmonization: The Real Book in the Style of Take 6*

Is “non-conformant harmonization“ the answer I was looking for in this question?

or  is this the term for computed harmonization and arrangement?

Does any one out there some experience with  automatical harmonization?

Comment: Please post the context of the phrase. That will be helpful in answering.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a link to the relevant paper would be of service: http://computationalcreativity.net/iccc2014/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/7.2_Pachet.pdf

It seems as if the idea is to use a Markov Chain to model harmony but with probabilities allowing some extended chords to be used as well as the usual triads, sevenths, and ninths.

Editorial: I prefer to just use simpler chords and model (or analyze) some of the additions as non-chord tones (though that has its own problems.)